# rendering a nested objected in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a hard time to render a nested object on to a reactjs page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Toolpanel from "./Todopanel";
import Toollist from "./Toollist";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      city: "Auckland",
      cityWeather: {}
    };
    this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this);
  }

  updateUser(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    let item = {
      text: entry,
      key: Date.now()
    };
    this.setState(prevstate => {
      return {
        users: prevstate.users.concat(item)
      };
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let apiId = "***************************";
    let city = this.state.city;
    let ApiString =
      "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
      city +
      "&APPID=" +
      apiId;
    fetch(ApiString)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ cityWeather: data }));
  }

  render() {
    let test = this.state.cityWeather;

    return (
      <div>
        <Toolpanel parentUpdate={this.updateUser} />

        <div>wind speed : {test.wind.speed} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have added my JSON file that I received from my weather API

```
//Json file
{
  "coord": { "lon": 174.77, "lat": -36.85 },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 293.7,
    "pressure": 1018,
    "humidity": 77,
    "temp_min": 293.15,
    "temp_max": 294.26
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": { "speed": 5.1, "deg": 360 },
  "clouds": { "all": 92 },
  "dt": 1553672420,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 7345,
    "message": 0.0043,
    "country": "NZ",
    "sunrise": 1553624951,
    "sunset": 1553667823
  },
  "id": 2193733,
  "name": "Auckland",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I am trying to render the wind speed from the JSON to my page.. but is throwing me a error message saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined"...Please help. I am fairly new to ReactJs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code, here is the sequence of events:

1. Component is created, i.e. `constructor` is called
2. Component is mounted, i.e. `componentDidMount` is called
3. `componentDidMount` starts an `async` request to fetch the data which is then parsed and set in state.
4. `render` method tries to read the data from state.

Now, since the request in #3 is an async one, it may not have completed in time when the `render` method has been called the first time.

So, you need to check if your request has completed or failed or is running.

You can use that to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the content in your render method.

**Recommended reading**
The official reactjs blog entry on [async rendering with examples of when data is fetched from an external resource](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data)

Answer (score 2):

You're not wrong the way you approached it. The error you're getting is because the fetch you're performing is taking some time, and render first executes without having the data populated.

So first time it gets in your render method the value of `test = {}`. So `test.wind.speed` will throw an error.

Instead, show a loading state of some sort or simply `return null` until the call is performed:

```
render() {
    let test = this.state.cityWeather;
    if (!test) {
        return 'Loading...';
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the properties too fast since `fetch` is an asynchronous call it will take some time but your `render` fires before that already.

Use it like this

```
{ test && <div>wind speed : {test.wind.speed} </div>}
```

Comment: still not working mate ... when I console.log(this.state.cityWeather.wind) ... its shows ..   { "speed": 5.1, "deg": 360 } which makes sense... but when I try console.log(this.state.cityWeather.wind.speed) .. it is throwing the error..

Answer (score 1):

Initially your test will be null as you haven't received any response from your API so you should check the variable presence before using it. So just check if it is present before using it like this:

```
render() {
    let test = this.state.cityWeather;

    return (
      <div>
        <Toolpanel parentUpdate={this.updateUser} />

        <div>wind speed : {test && test.wind && test.wind.speed ? test.wind.speed : ''} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post `ToolPanel` Component implementation, I may be wrong (I'm missing some information). But, I'm also pretty sure that your problem is not having a `loading` variable.

Basically, the first time `render()` method is called, you have `this.state.cityWeather` to be an empty object `{}`; that is because you fetch the data in `componentDidMount()`. Thus, the first time `render()` is called, being `this.state.cityWeather` empty, you cannot access `this.state.cityWeather.wind.speed` because you don't have the property `wind` in `this.state.cityWeather`!

So, usually, the common way to do this is adding a property `loading` in the state, and setting it to `true` in the `constructor`. Then, in the callback of the fetch, while you set the data in `this.state.cityWeather`, you also set `loading` to `true`.
Finally, in the `render()` method you wrote a conditional rendering: if `this.state.loading === true`, then you print a simple paragraph like `<p>I'm retrieving info!</p>`, otherwhise, if `this.state.loading === false`, you can render what you want.